# MERGE statement DELETE alternative in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Query using T-SQL MERGE Statement. Due to performance issues I am re writing the Query using `IF Exists Update` and `If Not Exists Insert`. I am able to write Insert/Update without any issue. But I am unable to handle the DELETE. Can some one please help me on this?

Here is the sample

```
---SAMPLE MERGE STATEMENT
MERGE 
   member_topic AS target
USING 
   someOtherTable AS source
ON 
   target.mt_member = source.mt_member 

WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE SET target.mt_notes = source.mt_notes
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
   INSERT (mt_member, mt_topic, mt_notes) VALUES (source.mt_member, source.mt_notes)

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
DELETE member_topic;


--UPDATE

UPDATE T SET T.mt_notes = S.mt_notes
FROM member_topic T 
JOIN someOtherTable S ON T.mt_member=S.mt_member


--INSERT

INSERT INTO member_topic(mt_member, mt_topic, mt_notes)   
SELECT mt_member, mt_topic, mt_notes 
FROM someOtherTable S 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM member_topic T 
                 WHERE T.mt_member=S.mt_member)
```

How to handle

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
DELETE member_topic;
```

in single DELETE Statement.

Comment: Sure Please post sample code what you have done so far

Comment: Post your database structure, sample code, what you want, and what you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

a sample script to be embedded between begin and end in proc

```
   MERGE dbo.Tablet AS TARGET
     USING dbo.QueryView AS SOURCE 
    ON ( 
        TARGET.[ID] = SOURCE.[ID] 
        )

 WHEN MATCHED 

  THEN
 UPDATE SET

 TARGET.[ID] = SOURCE.[ID]

 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
 INSERT (ID, [Name]  )
 VALUES (SOURCE.[ID], SOURCE.[Name]  )

 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
 DELETE;
```

Comment: how to handle WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
 DELETE; in single DELETE statement

Comment: @Ram if You are doing Incremental Loading then delete command is not required. Single statement is enough to delete all records which are not matched by source, unless you want to delete specific rows

Comment: AFAIU OP struggles to replace a single MERGE statement with 3 separate statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DELETE T
FROM member_topic T 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM someOtherTable S 
                 WHERE T.mt_member=S.mt_member)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE t
FROM member_topic t
    LEFT JOIN someOtherTable s ON t.mt_member = s.mt_member
WHERE s.mt_member IS NULL
```